# Knockoutjs - empty json

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I'm in the process of learning knockout and in my little sample, I am unable to get my json results. Can someone please tell me what I am missing?

```
ko.utils.stringifyJson(self.divisions)
```

Thanks

[click here to view source on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mpaul3133/tshUx/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ko.utils.stringifyJson` is not recursive so it only unwraps the first level observables and won't unwrap complex object.

So it won't unwrap your `Division` object properties (e.g `age`) in your collection.

However the [KO mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) has the recursive versions:

You can convert an observable into a plain JavaScript object with `ko.toJS` then call the `ko.utils.stringifyJson`:

```
ko.utils.stringifyJson(ko.toJS(self.divisions)
```

Or you can convert a viewmodel into JSON in one step with the `ko.toJSON` method

```
ko.toJSON(self.divisions)
```

See [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/32RVJ/).